# login en aspx con lenguaje VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Buen Dia
Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicacion web en ASPX con lenguaje VB.NET, ya tengo el form del login y por el momento hago el login con codigo validando los TextBox igualandolos manualmente a un usuario especifico.

Utilizo Visual Web Developer Express 2008 ,Lenguaje VB.NET

```
If txtusr.Text = "admin" And txtpwd.Text = "admin" Then
        Server.Transfer("index.aspx", True)
    Else
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('Error en usuario / contraseña');", True)
        txtusr.Text = ""
        txtpwd.Text = ""
```

He programado en VB.NET en desktop pero no en ASP.NET , no se si se utilizan cookies para guardar un ID de sesion o algun objeto session en ASP.

Tengo una pagina index que redirecciono al usuario cuando el login es correcto, pero si yo tecleo esa pagina en el navegador, entra sin mas sin haberse logeado entonces requiero redirigirlo al login si no tiene una sesion iniciada, he buscado en internet pero no he encontrado algo que pueda entender.

Mi web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">

</authentication>
```

¿Alguien podria proporcionarme un ejemplo o que deberia buscar especificamente en la documentacion?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mírate este ejemplo. Aquí se construye en login en asp.net:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx